# optimization of gcd calculation

Tags: c, optimization

I have an algorithm which is heavily based on the use of the greatest common divisor of signed integers, so I'm trying to get it faster. Please do not tell me that this kind of optimization is unnecessary, because I've already improved performance by 50%. I'm not seeing any potential to optimizations left, but I'm probably wrong.

In the following code, it's asserted that b != 0

```
Integer gcd(Integer a, Integer b)
{
   if ( a == 0 )
   {
      return b;
   }
   if ( a == b )
   {
      return a;
   }
   const Integer mask_a = (a >> (sizeof(Integer) * 8 - 1));
   a = (a + mask_a) ^ mask_a; // a = |a|
   const Integer mask_b = (b >> (sizeof(Integer) * 8 - 1));
   b = (b + mask_b) ^ mask_b; // b = |b|
   if ( ~a & 1 )
   {
      if ( b & 1 )
      {
         // 2 divides a but not b
         return gcd(a >> 1, b);
      }
      else
      {
         // both a and b are divisible by 2, thus gcd(a, b) == 2 * gcd( a / 2, b / 2)
         return gcd(a >> 1, b >> 1) << 1;
      }
   }
   if ( ~b & 1 )
   {
      // 2 divides b, but not a
      return gcd(a, b >> 1);
   }
   if ( a > b )
   {
      // since both a and b are odd, a - b is divisible by 2
      // gcd(a, b) == gcd( a - b, b)
      return gcd((a - b) >> 1, b);
   }
   else
   {
      // since both a and b are odd, a - b is divisible by 2
      // gcd(a, b) == gcd( a - b, b)
      return gcd((b - a) >> 1, a);
   }
}
```

As a side note: Integer is either `int`, `long` or `long long`. it's a typedef somewhere above.

As you see, theres an optimization in bringing a and b to its respective absolute value which works fine on my machine (not necessarily on all afaik). I kind of dislike the branching mess. Is there any way of improving it?

Comment: Before tuning code, make sure you have the fastest algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer's_GCD_algorithm

Comment: @Paul Since he's using 32/64bit numbers only I doubt that the algorithm makes sense.

Comment: @Voo: possibly not - I was just trying to point out that there is at least one faster algorithm out there so as always it might be a good idea to review the available algorithms before wasting time on code optimisation for a possibly sub-optimal algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another variant, binary GCD with a lookup table for shifts,

```
typedef unsigned /* long long int */ UInteger;

Integer lookup(Integer a, Integer b) {
    static const int lut[] =
        { 8, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 5, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 6, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 5, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 7, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 5, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 6, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 5, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        , 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0
        };
    if (a == 0) return b;
    const Integer mask_a = a >> (sizeof(Integer) * 8 - 1);
    UInteger a1 = (a + mask_a) ^ mask_a;
    const Integer mask_b = b >> (sizeof(Integer) * 8 - 1);
    UInteger b1 = (b + mask_b) ^ mask_b;

    int sa = 0, sb = 0, shift;
    do {
        shift = lut[a1 & 0xFF];
        a1 >>= shift;
        sa += shift;
    }while(shift == 8);
    do {
        shift = lut[b1 & 0xFF];
        b1 >>= shift;
        sb += shift;
    }while(shift == 8);
    // sa holds the amount to shift the result by, the smaller of the trailing zeros counts
    if (sa > sb) sa = sb;
    // now a1 and b1 are both odd
    if (a1 < b1) {
        UInteger tmp = a1;
        a1 = b1;
        b1 = tmp;
    }
    while(b1 > 1) {
        do {
            a1 -= b1;
            if (a1 == 0){
                return (b1 << sa);
            }
            do {
                a1 >>= (shift = lut[a1 & 0xFF]);
            }while(shift == 8);
        }while(b1 < a1);
        do {
            b1 -= a1;
            if (b1 == 0){
                return (a1 << sa);
            }
            do {
                b1 >>= (shift = lut[b1 & 0xFF]);
            }while(shift == 8);
        }while(a1 < b1);
    }
    return (1 << sa);
}
```

On my box, that is a bit faster than the Euclidean algorithm, which is a lot faster than the recursive binary GCD or the one without lookup table for the shifts. The version with a 16-element lookup table was slightly slower than Euclid.

If your inputs are very small, however, as you stated in a comment, it might be faster to compute a lookup table for the GCDs themselves, at least for small `a` and `b` (say `0 <= a,b <= 50`), and only fall back to the calculation when the inputs are larger than the lookup table allows.

Comment: even though this didn't improve my code, this was at least not worse and a fresh idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I've done some testing and simple algorithm like this:

```
int gcd(int a,int b)
{
    while(1)
    {
        int c = a%b;
        if(c==0)
          return abs(b);
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
}
```

Is around 5x faster than your code.

---

Try this one:

```
Integer gcd( Integer a, Integer b )
{
    if( a == b )
        return a;

    if( a == 0 )
        return b;

    if( b == 0 )
        return a;

    while( b != 0 ) { 
        Integer t = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = t;
    }

    return a;
}
```

It's @unkulunkulu's code + your IFs at the begining. It will be faster if your input has lots of trivial cases. Unfortunately, if that's the case, it won't be much faster than your code and you cannot do much about it.

Comment: did you use some special compiler flags? this is slower in my use case..

Comment: +1, weird implementation though

Comment: @unkulunkulu why do you consider this weird? It's the intuitive algorithm for me, but it's still the one I've replace with the faste one I posted.

Comment: @stefan, a bit too many words in it `while( b != 0 ) {
       Integer t = b;
       b = a % b;
       a = t;
    } return a;
` is shorter and works for `b=0` for example

Comment: @stefan I've tested various compilation flags and input data. My function is never slower than yours. What compiler and platform are you using? Maybe you have some specific input data?

Comment: I'm using an 32bit Ubuntu with kernel 3.2.0 with gcc and -O3. Yes, it may be the input data, but nevertheless, I do not gain any speedup

Comment: @stefan, what is your typical input then? where it comes from? can you provide a little sample? Also, provide details by editing your question instead of just answering in the comments so everyone could see it.

Comment: @unkulunkulu Usually, the numbers I put in, I expect them to be small, but I cannot assert that. I doubt there is one good little example. It's in the details and some compiler magic. Obviously both algorithms are fast, but it will be called 24930235 times just in the smallest use case. So every single instruction and branch counts.

Comment: @stefan, I mean, when you run your tests, what does the input look like? because I've tested several samples and every time simple euclidean algorithm works faster. Not 5x faster tbh, but around 30% faster.

Comment: @unkulunkulu testing the same algorithm 5times, on average my algorithm takes 4.480s +/-0.008s to run while your version takes 4.734s +/-0.030s. I do not have specific input data I manually test it with, this is just as it occurs in my program.

Comment: @stefan, you can just print the numbers that are coming into your function. I'm not asking to present the whole output, but some information would be interesting: average inputs, something else notable about it etc

Comment: @unkulunkulu usually I think they are between -1000 and 1000, most of them probably in the range of -50 to 50. I don't see why this should be significant to the question which is faster

Comment: @stefan, for example, if input is always 1, 1, then you get almost zero running time, on the other hand for large numbers you have to perform many divisions. Still doesn't make sense why speed depends on the input?

Comment: Actually, I'm not calculating the gcd if a is -1 or 1 which got be an improvement. Yep, I'm still not seeing why it should be faster. % isn't exactly a fast calculation

Comment: @stefan Whether the Euclidean algorithm or the binary GCD algorithm is faster depends on the machine, compiler, and implementation (of the algorithm). On my old 32-bit box, binary was a big win over Euclid, on my 64-bit box, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize this by replacing the recursion with a loop. Even if your compiler optimizes the tail recursive calls into jumps, you'll still be doing unnecessary checks for `a == 0` and absolute value computations in the recursive calls.

To handle the non-tail recursion `gcd(a >> 1, b >> 1) << 1`, you'll have to introduce an accumulator variable that starts at zero and is used to left-shift the result prior to `return`.

Example (untested):

```
Integer gcd(Integer a, Integer b)
{
    const Integer mask_a = a >> (sizeof(Integer) * 8 - 1);
    a = (a + mask_a) ^ mask_a;
    const Integer mask_b = b >> (sizeof(Integer) * 8 - 1);
    b = (b + mask_b) ^ mask_b;

    int shift = 0;
    while (a != 0 && a != b) {
        if (~a & 1) {
            a >>= 1;
            if (!(b & 1)) {
                b >>= 1;
                shift++;
            }
        } else if (~b & 1) {
            b >>= 1;
        } else if (a > b) {
            a = (a - b) >> 1;
        } else {
            b = (b - a) >> 1; // the error was here and i have to write 6 chars about it, formerly it was a = (b - a) >> 1;
        }
    }
    return b << shift;
}
```

Comment: your untested algorithm can run into a infinite loop, i'll try to fix that

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler support it, you can use built-in functions like `likely()` or `unlikely()`  for each `if()` which will allow the compiler to do more optimizations.

These functions are defined in the Linux kernel. With gcc it is replaced with `__builtin_expect()`.

Comment: Sadly there was no improvement with this. I think that all cases are approximately equally probable, so at least in my case it doesn't give me an improvement